# Array[] for lists with vector-like functions

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to use Array[] or a similar function that gives out a list of vector-like functions evaluated at different numbers. For a scalar function f this is perfectly doable with Array[]:

```
f[x_] = x^2;
Array[f,3]

(*
{1,4,9}
*)
```

If f was not a scalar function and if I wanted to include other vectors as well I would expect something like:

```
a[x_] = {x,1,1+x^2};
b[x_] = {x,x^2,x^3};

Function[{a[x],b[x]},3]

(*
{{{1,1,2},{2,1,5},{3,1,10}},{{1,1,1},{2,4,8},{3,9,27}}
}
*)
```

One can see that a[x] was evaluated at x = 1, 2, 3 and then b[x] was appended at values x = 1, 2, 3 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array` in several alternative ways:

```
Array[#, 3] & /@ {a, b}

Map[Array[#, 3] &] @ {a, b}

Transpose @ Array[Through @ {a, b} @ # &, 3]

Array[Through @ {a, b} @ # &, 3, 1 , Transpose[{##}] &]
```

all give

> {{{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 5}, {3, 1, 10}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 4, 8}, {3, 9, 27}}}

Alternatively, you can use `Table`:

```
Table[i[j], {i, {a, b}}, {j, 3}]
```

or

```
Transpose @ Table[{a[x], b[x]}, {x, 3}]
```

to get

> {{{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 5}, {3, 1, 10}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 4, 8}, {3, 9, 27}}}